# How to run function of a Component from a button of another Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the component TimeDisplay where I have the function handleTimer.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import format from './formatTime';

class TimeDisplay extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            time: 0,
            on: false,
        }
    }

    handleTimer = () => {
        if (this.state.on) {
            clearInterval(this.timer);
        } else {
            this.timer = setInterval(() => {
                this.setState({time: ++this.state.time})
                console.log("timer running");
            }, 10)
        }
        this.setState({on: !this.state.on})
    }

    render() {
        var time = format(this.state.time);
        return <div>
            <div className="controls">
                <button onClick={this.handleTimer}>Run</button>
            </div>
            <h1 className="display-time">{time}</h1>
        </div>
    }
}

export default TimeDisplay;
```

Now, what I'd like to do is create a button that behaves exactly like the one in render(), but in another component. How do I do it?

Comment: you'll have to use the other component as a child of TimeDisplay and pass that function as a prop. in `TimeDisplay ` do  `<OtherComp handleTimer={this.handleTimer} />`

Comment: If the other component is in the same tree as TimeDisplay you need to pass down the function as a prop. If the other component isn't in the same tree you need to either lift the state up to a common ancestor or share the function through a state manager tool (e.g. redux)

Comment: you basically reuse this component and do `< TimeDisplay />`

Answer (score 0):

If you have two components then keep the button in one component and import into second component and pass handleTimer functions as props to that component below i am giving example

```
    import React, {Component} from "react";
    import format from './formatTime';

    class ButtonAction extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                time: 0,
                on: false,
            }
        }

        handleTimer=()=>{
          this.props.handleTimer();
        }

        render() {
            var time = format(this.state.time);
            return <div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <button onClick={this.handleTimer}>Run</button>
                </div>
                <h1 className="display-time">{time}</h1>
            </div>
        }
    }

    export default ButtonAction ;
```

import NewComponent in TimeDisplay  component

```
import NewComponent from "./ButtonAction ";
import React, {Component} from "react";
import format from './formatTime';

    class TimeDisplay extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                time: 0,
                on: false,
            }
        }

        handleTimer = () => {
            if (this.state.on) {
                clearInterval(this.timer);
            } else {
                this.timer = setInterval(() => {
                    this.setState({time: ++this.state.time})
                    console.log("timer running");
                }, 10)
            }
            this.setState({on: !this.state.on})
        }

        render() {
            var time = format(this.state.time);
            return <div>
                <NewComponent handleTimer ={this.handleTimer}  /> 
            </div>
        }
    }

    export default TimeDisplay;
```